# Issue with API call to Tradier using R with httr package

Tags: r, api, httr, tradier

I'm trying to make an API call to tradier API, but get 401 error. Here's the link to their API: https://developer.tradier.com/documentation/markets/get-quotes

And it's my simple code:

```
library(httr)
tradier <- "https://api.tradier.com/v1/markets/history?symbol=AAPL"
getdata<-GET(url=tradier, add_headers(Authorization="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
getdata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sandbox` API endpoint works for me. I guess for the `brokerage` API endpoint you have to upgrade your account.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(httr)

token <- keyring::key_get("tradier_token")
url <- "https://sandbox.tradier.com/v1/markets/quotes?symbols=AAPL,MSFT"
resp <- GET(url = url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", token)))
content(resp)[[1]] %>%
  data.table::rbindlist()
#>               V1             V2
#>  1:         AAPL           MSFT
#>  2:    Apple Inc Microsoft Corp
#>  3:            Q              Q
#>  4:        stock          stock
#>  5:       217.66         114.26
#>  6:        -2.38            0.7
#>  7:        -1.08           0.61
#>  8:     96246748       71229698
#>  9:     26803955       24017088
#> 10:     33973603       21492554
#> 11:  1.53756e+12    1.53756e+12
#> 12:       220.78            114
#> 13:       221.36         115.29
#> 14:       217.29         113.51
#> 15:       217.66         114.26
#> 16:       220.03         113.57
#> 17:       229.67          113.8
#> 18:       149.16          72.92
#> 19:       217.75         113.81
#> 20:            1              9
#> 21:            K              P
#> 22: 1.537574e+12   1.537574e+12
#> 23:       218.02         113.95
#> 24:            2              3
#> 25:            P              P
#> 26: 1.537574e+12   1.537574e+12
#> 27:         AAPL           MSFT
#>               V1             V2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>